# Dagger test component not found

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have created the following test class. The problem is that DaggerTestDiComponent is not being found - even though I can see it in the build directory.

I have looked through similar SO questions but they seem to concern older versions of gradle/Dagger2 and don't seem to apply (at least from what I can see). My app Dagger code is working OK.

```
public class TestMvpEngineeringPresenter {

@Mock
IMvpEngineeringView iMvpEngineeringView;

@Inject
MvpEngineeringPresenter mvpEngineeringPresenter;

@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Before
public void setUp() {

    TestDiComponent component = DaggerTestDiComponent.builder()
            .testAppModule(new TestAppModule()).build();
    component.inject(this);
}

@Test
public void testStationControlSwitchChange() {

    mvpEngineeringPresenter.assignEngineeringView(iMvpEngineeringView);
    mvpEngineeringPresenter.onLoad();

    mvpEngineeringPresenter.switchChanged(new SwitchChange(0, true));
    assertEquals(true, mvpEngineeringPresenter.iStationModel.getStationControls().get(0).isOnOff());
    mvpEngineeringPresenter.switchChanged(new SwitchChange(0, false));
    assertEquals(false, mvpEngineeringPresenter.iStationModel.getStationControls().get(0).isOnOff());
}
```

}

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.fisincorporated.mvc_mvp_mvvm"
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


// Android support stuff
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'


// Butterknife - also includes library for Dagger
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

// For MVP Observer/Subscriber
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'

// For Dagger2
// compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'  // Added above for ButterKnife
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'

// For testing
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

// Mockito of course!
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
testAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'

}
```

Here's TestDiComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {TestAppModule.class})  // comma separated list of  classes
public interface TestDiComponent {

    void inject(TestMvpEngineeringPresenter testMvpEngineeringPresenter);

}
```

Here is TestAppModule

```
@Module
public class TestAppModule {

@Provides
public IStationModel getStationModel() {

    IStationModel iStationModel = Mockito.mock(IStationModel.class);
    when(iStationModel.getStationName()).thenReturn("Mocked Station");
    when(iStationModel.getStationControls().size()).thenReturn(2);
    when(iStationModel.getBigButtonName()).thenReturn(("Log Button"));
    when(iStationModel.getLogHint()).thenReturn("Enter log text here");

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        when(iStationModel.getStationControls().get(i)).thenReturn(new StationControl("Test Switch" + i,false));
    }
    return iStationModel;
}

@Provides
public MvpEngineeringPresenter getMvpEngineeringPresenter() {
    return new MvpEngineeringPresenter();
}

}
```

Comment: if its getting compiled then defintely class is there in your app... keeping in mind AS
#1. close app from recent on phone and then Run the project because sometimes AS just implements ur latest change...
#2. in setup() add a timer to call that code after say 2 seconds just to confirm its because of loading that class ( just to confirm )


for further i think a bit more of the code or flow will help ( atleast for me :) )

Ignore if it does not helps...

Comment: I tried #1 with no luck. I can't do #2 due to the compile problem. I did add addition code (TestDiComponent and TestAppModule) from my project.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are locating the classes under your androidTest folder and you are not adding dagger-compile lib as `androidTestCompileAnnotationProcessor` / `androidTestCompileAnnotationProcessor` to your gradle app file. That is not allowing dagger compiler to generate you DaggerXXX classes under your androidTest folder.

Comment: I am actually doing this under the test (not androidTest) domain.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to add comment on this but formatting was lousy so I will add as answer but it is somewhat incomplete.

Android Studio still says it can't find the generated DaggerTestDiComponent class, but my code does execute and the test runs.

For reference build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
 compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
 defaultConfig {
  applicationId "com.fisincorporated"
  minSdkVersion 25
  targetSdkVersion 25
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0"
  testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

  dataBinding {
   enabled = true
  }
 }
 buildTypes {
  release {
   minifyEnabled false
   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
  }
 }
}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

 // Android support stuff
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'



 // Butterknife - also includes library for Dagger
 compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
 compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
 provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
 annotationProcessor('com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0', {
  exclude group: 'com.android.support',
  module: 'support-annotations'
 })

 // For MVP Observer/Subscriber
 compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
 compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'

 // For Dagger2
 // compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'  // Added above for ButterKnife
 annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'

 // For testing
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

 // Mockito
 testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.4.0'
 testAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
  //provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

 // For Android/Mockito testing
 androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5', {
  exclude group: 'com.android.support',
  module: 'support-annotations'
 })
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
 androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+'
 androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
 androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'

 // Android espresso testing
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
   exclude group: 'com.android.support',
   module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  // androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'   added above
  // following added to get past version conflict
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
}
```

I also modified my TestAppModule.getStationModel to not mock my StationModel class as I wasn't able to mock it the way I thought I could (I am just learning Mockito). So here that is:

```
@Module
public class TestAppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public IStationModel getStationModel() {

        IStationModel iStationModel =  StationModel.getStationModel();
        return iStationModel;
    }

    @Provides
    public MvpEngineeringPresenter getMvpEngineeringPresenter(IStationModel istationModel) {
        return new MvpEngineeringPresenter(istationModel);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added

```
 testAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}'
```

and it works for me